# ASP - Server.CreateObject returns nothing, Classic ASP

Tags: vb.net, asp-classic, .net-assembly

Team,

The following code returns empty/null to myobj, in my classic ASP page while trying to invoke a dll component.

```
Set myobj = Server.CreateObject("MODULENAME.cCLASSNAME")
```

This is related to a DLL which is placed alongside this asp page under \Bin. The DLL is an Interop COM dll custom developed by a former colleague and currently there's no access to the code.

The DLL components are appearing in the regEdit under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ which makes me assume it is registered. However when I try to re-register using regsvr32, it shows that it was loaded but couldn't find DLLRegisterServer method. I use regAsm to register the component.

Any alternate approach that can be done here? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this a DLL you created? Is it a COM DLL? Is this your local machine or the web server? What do you mean when you say the code fails? You need to supply a whole lot more info if you want help here.

Comment: Sorry about that Steve, I've updated the query with some additional details you had requested. Please let me know if there's any more information I can add.

Answer (score 0):

If the file name starts with "Interop" or "AxInterop", it is likely a wrapper to a COM DLL, not the DLL it's self. The COM DLL must be registered on the system and then a dotNet application will use/create that wrapper so you can make calls to it.

What you need to do is find the DLL, not the Interop because you are not using dotNet in Classic ASP. Make sure it is registered on that computer (using regsvr32 without error) and then this should work.

Last note/hint, that dll created by ex-coworker was done in C or VB (not dotNet) right? If done in dotNet, it is not COM and you need to research "How to call a managed DLL from unmanaged code".